# Keeping stats for when a direct link to image is used?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, analytics

Not sure if this would fall here or Webmasters so I apologize in advance.

Currently I have an image viewer written in PHP that uses a rewrite to change:

http://example.com/image/s8d8s.png to http://example.com/s8d8s

When they load this viewer it will display the image with all kinds of links and stats for the image. It also connects to my MySQL database and adds a view to the stats table. So that I can show how many views each image has.

The issue: When a use right-clicks on an image in the viewer and gets the image's direct link(http://example.com/image/s8d8s.png) and uses that by sending it to a friend or embedding it on a website, I want to be able to track that and add a view to my database.

Is there a way I can manipulate the apache rewrite to trick a browser into thinking it's viewing a image direct link but it be a PHP file that will add a view?

Comment: What image viewer do you have? Show us code please.

Comment: @lolka_bolka I rewrote the question and hopefully it makes more sense. This has nothing to do with my viewer so I hope it's easier to understand now.

Comment: Check the "referer" field in the server's logs.

Comment: @BobBrown Yeah that is always an option, but I was hoping I could find an easier way to achieve this.

Comment: The browser has to be able to request `http://example.com/image/s8d8s.png` and receive image data, otherwise it would not be able to display the image even when it is surrounded by all the stuff your image viewer outputs.